# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on very large string

Tags: java, html, string

I am trying to parse a String that is the HTML from a page from my web browser application, for the HTML that is the data that I am trying to retrieve. (In short, I am doing some web-scraping of Google Images results.)

My function, find(), seems to work really well for decently-sized Strings, but the minute that it encounters the full String that is the HTML of the code that I am trying to parse, it complains of a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is my find() function, and the function that I am trying to call it from:

find():

```
// helper functions
    public static int find(String stringToFind, int startPos, String str) throws NullPointerException,
        IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // make sure that neither argument is null and not an empty String
        if ((stringToFind == null) || (str == null))
            throw new NullPointerException("null arguments are not allowed.");
        if ((stringToFind.equals("")) || (str.equals("")))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String arguments must be non-empty.");
        int position = startPos;
        // while we are not at the end of the String and the stringToFind is not found
        while (position != str.length())
        {
            // find the first character in the string
            position = str.indexOf(stringToFind.charAt(0), position+1);
            // if found
            if (position != -1)
            {
                int j = 0;
                // search the other characters in str for the other characters in stringToFind
                // while there is a character in str that matches its respective character in 
                //  stringToFind and we are not at the end of either str,stringToFind
                int firstCharacterPosition = -1;
                while ((str.charAt(position) == stringToFind.charAt(j)) &&
                        ((position < str.length()) && (j < stringToFind.length())))
                {
                    if (firstCharacterPosition == -1)
                        firstCharacterPosition = position;
                    // compare the next character in str with the next character in stringToFind
                    // if the characters match and the characters being matched is the last 
                    //  character in stringToFind
                    if ((str.charAt(++position) == stringToFind.charAt(++j)) &&
                        (j == stringToFind.length() - 1))
                        // we are done here
                        return firstCharacterPosition;
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
        return -1;  
    }
```

the function(s) that uses find():

```
public String getUserQuery()
    {
        // find the element in the HTML that starts with "<input id=\"gbqfq\"" and return it
        index = find("<input id=\"gbqfq\"", index, searchPageHTML);
        System.out.printf("index == %d", index);
        try
        {
            return searchPageHTML.substring(index, 
                searchPageHTML.indexOf('>', index));
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException outOfBounds)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The whole class (which I pass the large String that is the HTML code):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;


public class SearchResultsHTMLParser
{
    private String searchPageHTML;
    private int index = -1;
    public SearchResultsHTMLParser(String html)
    {
        this.searchPageHTML = html;
        // setup a test GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GoogleImageTest");
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html",
            this.getImagesDiv());
        frame.add(editorPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // make methods that parse this.html for the user input and the images
    /* The user input has an HTML id of "gbqfq", and the images all belong to the HTML class 
     * "rg_di". The function for the user input should return the value of the input field as a
     * String, and the function for the images should simply return the substring that has all 
     * of the images in it. (This will be parsed further for each individual image.)
     */
    public String getUserQuery()
    {
        // find the element in the HTML that starts with "<input id=\"gbqfq\"" and return it
        index = find("<input id=\"gbqfq\"", index, searchPageHTML);
        System.out.printf("index == %d", index);
        try
        {
            return searchPageHTML.substring(index, 
                searchPageHTML.indexOf('>', index));
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException outOfBounds)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    /* This function will get the div with id="rg_s", and will probably not be used */
    public String getImagesDiv()
    {
        System.out.println("index == " + index);
        index = find("<div id=\"rg_s\"", index, searchPageHTML);
        System.out.println("index == " + index);
        System.out.printf("charAt(%d) == %c", index, searchPageHTML.charAt(index));
        String startOfNextDiv = "<div jsl="; 
        int nextDivPos = find(startOfNextDiv, index, searchPageHTML);
        // return the substring of searchPageHTML from the start of the found image div container
        //  to the end of it (it's ok if there is whitespace, so we could go up until the start of
        //  next div container)
        return searchPageHTML.substring(index, nextDivPos);
    }

    // helper functions
    public static int find(String stringToFind, int startPos, String str) throws NullPointerException,
        IllegalArgumentException
    {
        // make sure that neither argument is null and not an empty String
        if ((stringToFind == null) || (str == null))
            throw new NullPointerException("null arguments are not allowed.");
        if ((stringToFind.equals("")) || (str.equals("")))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String arguments must be non-empty.");
        int position = startPos;
        // while we are not at the end of the String and the stringToFind is not found
        while (position != str.length())
        {
            // find the first character in the string
            position = str.indexOf(stringToFind.charAt(0), position+1);
            // if found
            if (position != -1)
            {
                int j = 0;
                // search the other characters in str for the other characters in stringToFind
                // while there is a character in str that matches its respective character in 
                //  stringToFind and we are not at the end of either str,stringToFind
                int firstCharacterPosition = -1;
                while ((str.charAt(position) == stringToFind.charAt(j)) &&
                        ((position < str.length()) && (j < stringToFind.length())))
                {
                    if (firstCharacterPosition == -1)
                        firstCharacterPosition = position;
                    // compare the next character in str with the next character in stringToFind
                    // if the characters match and the characters being matched is the last 
                    //  character in stringToFind
                    if ((str.charAt(++position) == stringToFind.charAt(++j)) &&
                        (j == stringToFind.length() - 1))
                        // we are done here
                        return firstCharacterPosition;
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
        return -1;  
    }

    public static String getSubstringOf(String str, String subString, int pos)
    {
        // first, make a call to find(subString, pos, str)
        int result = SearchResultsHTMLParser.find(subString, pos, str);
        // return the substring if it exists, that is if find() != -1
        return (result == -1) ? "" : subString;
    }

}
```

---

**What I am thinking about doing**

I was thinking about converting the large String to a large char[], and then try to rewrite my functions to use that, block-by-block. I plan on this because I think the error is with the sheer size of the String that is the HTML to any Google Image Search result, which is hundreds of thousands of characters long.

Comment: Is this error due to the sheer size of the HTML String? (To test the code, all you have to do is give it the HTML from a Google Image search result.)

Comment: to me this is a mayhem. narrow down the section that troubles you

Comment: Should I, for improved testability, include the code that creates an Object of the class with the HTML code passed to it?

Comment: The getImagesDiv() is where the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is being thrown from, on line with the following code: `int nextDivPos = find(startOfNextDiv, index, searchPageHTML);`

Comment: do not think I try to be mean. nobody will even take a look at this code. your find fucntion is too complicated to understand. may be you should try to seat down and break it down to see where has gone wron

Comment: I am using it like the find function in C++.

Comment: why do not you try to see if there is better Java Api to help you? this is java code not C++.

Comment: I could find nothing in java.lang.String, and I didn't feel like searching for, and downloading, some other library for just one function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63068/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-mike-warren).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: for some reason, the elements that I was searching for did not exist in my Java-obtained HTML code. It had nothing to do with my function, and my function happened to do the same thing as an already-existing function that I was unaware of (until now): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int)

`System.out.println("Thanks, Kick Buttowski!!");`

Comment: I changed the code to my `getUserQuery()` program, because I found out that the HTML tag I was trying to retrieve was there, but in a different ordering of the attributes. However, with my new code, it's like the element still doesn't exist!! 

Here is the updated `getUserQuery()`: http://speedy.sh/pDGZe/getUserQuery.txt

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to scrape another site. Turns out that, for some reason, the HTML code has to be downloaded, and then the file has to be read, in order for the content to be found. 

For some reason, the HTML code seems a bit different as a String in the class, than it is printed either on-screen, or in the file. What is going on when HTML Strings get printed?